# Extract city and ZIP code from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript string of the format:

```
"New York City, New York 10024, United States"
```

The String contains city, state, ZIP code, and country information. I'm trying to fetch only the city name and ZIP code from the string but currently only being able to fetch the city name from the string.

**JavaScript Code**:

```
var sampleLocation = "New York City, New York 10024, United States";
var resLocation = sampleLocation.split(",");
console.log(resLocation);
console.log(resLocation[0].replace( /,/g, "" ));
```

**Output**:

```
["New York City", " New York 10024", " United States"]
New York City
```

I can't figure out how to extract the city and ZIP code efficiently. Is there a way to select the last six characters of an array element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the format of the string is fixed.

```
"City Name, PIN code, State"
```

You can use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
var address = "New York City, New York 10024, United States";
var locationArr = address.split(',');

var cityName = locationArr[0]; // New York City
var pinCode = locationArr[1].match(/\d+/)[0]; // 10024
// OR
// var pinCode = locationArr[1].replace(/\D+/g, '');

console.log('city: ', cityName, '\nPIN Code: ', pinCode);
```

---

> Is there a way to select the last six characters of an array element?

If the PIN code is always the last six characters in the string, you can also use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

```
var pinCode = locationArr[1].slice(-6);
```

[`String#substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) can also be used.

Comment: The above code is running properly in an online Js Editor but when i run the code from an html file I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined". Any idea why this error is being displayed?

Comment: @Lucy That means `locationArr[1]` is `undefined`. Debug by logging the `locationArr` to console. This also depends on how you're using it in HTML

Comment: Figured out the problem, I was trying to parse another string which had no Zip code hence getting the undefined error..Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What if the address format is not fixed?
1. City Name, PIN code, State;
2. PIN code, City Name, State;
3. City Name, State, PIN code;

Is there a way to extract the zip code from it?